# IP address in different formats

Tags: networking

Normally, we see IP address in this format:

"108.169.14.35",

however, if I convert it to "-o pipe" (old machine) format  ,it appears like this "0|0|0|1823018531"

Now I would like to understand what causes the IP address to look entirely different. And is there a way to convert it back from "-o pipe" to "normal" format ?

Comment: What is "-o pipe" (old machine) format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1823018531 is the IP address 108.169.14.35 written in decimal format. No way to know what the zeros are for.

To convert the decimal format to "dotted quad", the standard library of your programming language probably has a subroutine for it. if not, you get the numbers from last to first by dividing by 256 and taking the remainder, and then dividing by 256 again and taking the remainder, and repeating two more times.